# How do I combine multiple rows into one row in the same table but with different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

First up, my goal is that some job applicant should be able to upload some files and then submit the application.
A HR person in the company should be able to then export the data and the files.

Basically, I have one table with the data from some job applications (Name, Email etc.).

| ApplicantID | Name | Email | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | Bar | Yo |
| 2 | Foo | Bar | Yo |
| 3 | Foo | Bar | Yo |

I have another table with the relative paths and the file names of some files the applicant has uploaded.
Because of my somewhat clunky frontend design, the file table looks like this (Only the file names are represented):

| FileID | Letter | CV | Qualifications |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | Bar | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | Yo |

Is there any way to get it like this with a query?

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Bar | Yo |

I've had the idea of using a third m x n table like this:

| ApplicantID | FileID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

But here comes the question of how I can get the latest 3 added rows and get individual columns.

Comment: Please  give the table names, so it's easier to talk about. And explain what the sense of the secont table is. Do you have knowlege about table/database design? One question: why not add a column `ApplicantID` to the second table?

Comment: As@h.m.i.13 said, you should add `ApplicantID` column on the second table: when a user uploads a file, that file must be tied to its owner! With this, your query will just be easy using a `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JOIN** to join three table and get the column you need....but make sure you follow the normalization while designing the table